# Decent Open-Source Task Orchestration Software - is there such a thing?

Tags: task-management

I'm currently in a bit of a quandry. I'm looking for an application - preferably web-based - that I can organise some tasks (such as web requests or ssh-based commands) to kick off in either parallel or in sequence.

With most of these applications, it's an all or nothing gig. If one part fails, I have to start again which seems really counter-intuitive to me - I'd like to place rules and blocks so that perhaps the whole thing will pause if there's a problem with one of the steps.

I know there's HP Operations Orchestration out there, but it's really quite pricey and a bit over the top for what I'm looking for. I guess there are batch schedulers but then they come with all the data analysis and formatting stuff and again cost quite a bit.

Is it also too much to ask for something with a vaguely decent user interface? I can host it on pretty much any operating system within reason.

Does this idea exist? Or will I have to create my own? Am I even using the right terminology - is "Orchestration" what this is?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [this Job orchestration Q&A on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14879789/job-orchestration). The open source Job runner seems to have a web frontend and can chain jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the open source version of HP Operations Orchestration:
http://www.cloudslang.io/

(Disclaimer, i'm part of that project).

Also you should look at the free version of OO:
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/operations-orchestration-it-process-automation/try-now.html?jumpid=va_r11374_us/en/large/eb/go_ooce

Comment: Please try to make your answer self-containing.